# Save changes when tapping Back - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, master-detail

I have a Master Detail storyboard set up with a Navigation Controller. The Master view being a UITableView that shows a list of things saved using Core Data. When a row is tapped, it segues to a Detail view which has a UITextView where you can edit the data.

How can I call a function (or what exiting functions are available) that I can use to automatically save the changes when the User taps "Back" in the Navigation Bar?

Comment: Would be great if you can show some of the code that you have written

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to automatically save the changes.

All you have to do, is while you segue, you will have to pass the core data object along to the detail view controller.

The detail view controller will then edit the same object and save the object.

You can use -

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
```

Or

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
```

To know if the back button was pressed.

In that, all you have to do is change your core data object's property, and save it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.
`override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)`